# Cannot connect to SVN via SSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, svn, visualsvn-server

I am using the latest Ubuntu 18 LTS. 
I have a Windows 2003 server with Visual SVN.
I can connect to any SVN via another Windows PC using FireFox (`https://ipaddress/svn'`)

When I do this through Ubuntu + FireFox, it never accepts my user name and password.

When I do this through RabbitVCS SVN, I get this error

`Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication`

What could be wrong? Rabbit never even asks for a username or password.

Comment: Have you set-up your server/account to use Subversion authentication or Windows authentication? https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00039/

Answer (score 0):

The root cause should be TLS / SSL versions incompatibility. You should upgrade your server.

> I have a Windows 2003 server with Visual SVN.

It seems to me that you have a very old VisualSVN Server version. Modern versions of the product cannot be installed on Windows Server 2003. Note that VisualSVN Server 3.8 can be installed and supports Windows Server 2008 R2 and later.

Upgrade VisualSVN Server to the latest version.